# What does `<-` in a channel return type of a function in Go means?

Tags: go

I wonder what `<-` in a channel return type of a function in Go means. Indeed, a channel of type T is written as `chan T` and created using `make(chan T, N)`, so what does "`<-`" means in the return type of `time.After`?

```
go doc time.After
package time // import "time"

func After(d Duration) <-chan Time
    After waits for the duration to elapse and then sends the current time on
    the returned channel. It is equivalent to NewTimer(d).C. The underlying
    Timer is not recovered by the garbage collector until the timer fires. If
    efficiency is a concern, use NewTimer instead and call Timer.Stop if the
    timer is no longer needed.
```

**Bonus**:

How do I see from `go doc` that `time.After` is asynchronous and doesn't block until the duration has passed?

Comment: Please take [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) to answer such basic questions. Particularly the part about [channels](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2).

Comment: Also, your "Bonus" question is entirely unrelated, and should be in a separate question. It's also incorrect to call it "asynchronous".

Comment: Well, the documentation is indeed a bit confusing because the function `After` returns immediately. It doesn’t "wait" in the sense that it would block.  Another ambiguity is the "current time". Is the current relative to the call of `After` or when the time is written to the channel ? I know what `After` does. I just want to point out that the documentation is indeed unclear.

Comment: @Flimzy the tour doesn't cover directional channel references.

Comment: @Flimzy - why isn’t it asynchronous? When `After` writes to the channel, that’s an asynchronous operation?

Comment: Because the only way to get "asynchronous" in Go is with a goroutine, and there's no goroutine involved.

Comment: @Flimzy - I’m pretty sure that `After` starts a go routine... don’t you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<-chan time` means that `After` returns a *read only* channel of time values.

A `chan time` is a read and write channel.

Bonus:

You are right. The documentation is not clear enough. You have to kind of guess it from the signature.

You could maybe suggest a better and less ambiguous description of what `After` does. Go is an open source project and this would be an opportunity to contribute.